# Filter content for search text with lowercased and array

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, filter

I have struct with `cities: [String]` in **firestore**

```
struct CityList {
    var country: String
    var cities: [String]
}
```

Struct in firestore looks like on

```
1
    country: Russia
    cities: ["Moscow", "Saint-Petersburg"]
2
    country: USA
    cities: ["New York", "Los Angeles"]
```

I need to use filter array of strings `cities: [String]` when I use searchController. Now I have `func filterContentForSearchText`

```
private func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String) {
    filteredCityList = cityList.filter({ (cityList: CityList) -> Bool in
        return cityList.cities[0].lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
    })
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

I know with my mistake is -> `cities[0]`, but I don't understand how to fix it...

And when I write text in searchController, searchController search only first city it's **Moscow** or **New York**.

How I can search **Moscow, Saint-Petersburg, New York and Los Angeles**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So your cities[0] only takes the first city, I assume you need to search in all cities so I would check `cities.contains`. I would also use localizedCaseInsensitiveContains instead of manually lowercasing.

```
cities.contains {
    $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText)
}
```

the filter would be:

```
cityList.filter { list in
    list.cities.contains { city in
        city.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText)
    }
}
```

Comment: CityList is a Struct, value of type 'CityList' has no member 'filter'.

Comment: @MorisKramer correct, but cityList is an array containing CityList structs I assume from the example in the question. - edit: I think you meant to comment on the other answer.

Comment: Its more of a poor naming. "CityList" is not an array and should not use word "List" in it. Maybe something like "Country".

Comment: I agree but I think that's outside of the scope of the question, while we're at it "country" attribute should be "name" or "countryName"

Comment: Also note that "searchText" is a search phrase and your answer is at "list.cities.contains" won't find partial answers as it iterate over hashed values of exact copies.

Comment: @MorisKramer correct, but again, outside scope of this question

Answer (score 0):

```
let arrayFiltered = CityList.cities.filter{
       $0.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
}
```

Please try this.

Answer (score 0):

You trying to filter on Struct, it won't work. Try using filter on Array of cities instead.

---

I think your data structure can be improved like this:

```
let searchText = "Moscow"

 // for easch Country: Cities array
let worldCities: [String: [String]] = [ "Russia": ["Moscow", "Saint-Petersburg"],
                                        "USA": ["New York", "Los Angeles"]
                                        ]


let result = worldCities["Russia"]?.filter({ city -> Bool in
    if city.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
})
```

In case you want go over all countries, you should probably use single array of all cities or merge with above example:

```
let all = worldCities.values
```

Comment: You can assume from the question that OP is using an array of structs and not raw data.

Comment: Yes, I meant that I think this approach is not that good structuring your data. Your response its the correct one when dealing with struct array.